# VBA code to check if the result of formula is negative and if negative pop up a msgbox stating the error

Tags: excel, vba

I have following code, however this code is work in progress:

[image]

My intentions are to use table name instead of cell name (f7 and h7). Formula used in the sheet is

```
Pending Quantity (column f) = Total quantity(Column Issue till date (column e) -((issue from FSD Harduaganj (column g)) + (issue from SWC Aligarh (column H)))
```

and VBA code is to check if the entered quantity in column g or h makes the pending quantity negative, then clear that entered quantity.

Here is the current code, the code is referring to f7 and h7 however I intend to use it on whole column like... if I enter data in next row it should check if the pending quantity is negative if negative it should remove/clear the last entry from column g or h of that row.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim entrycell As Range
    Set Target = Me.Range("f7")
    Set entrycell = Me.Range("H7")

    If Target.Value < 0 Then
        MsgBox ("This Value must be a number of zero or greater."), , "Invalid Entry":entrycell.ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand, you do not define `Target`, it is the cell that has been changed and triggers this code.

Comment: Sir i am totally new to VBA, to be honest I am using this code in my work place. Please suggest what should i do to carry out the work.

Comment: So when someone enters something in G or H you want to check the corresponding value in F and if it's negative remove that last entry. Is that right?

Comment: You said *Pending Quantity (column f) = Total quantity(Column Issue till date (column e) -((issue from FSD Harduaganj (column g)) + (issue from SWC Aligarh (column H)))* so column G is the only one that can make F negative unless you can type negative values in H. Anyways, use Data Validation, it's easier

Comment: @SJR Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 7 Or Target.Column = 8 Then
    If Cells(Target.Row, "F") < 0 Then
        MsgBox ("This Value must be a number of zero or greater."), , "Invalid Entry"
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very very very much!!! It worked... thanks a ton.